# Centre 4 divs in a square layout CSS

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how to centre 4 div's in my CSS. I am looking to have them arranged in a square, ie, two on top and two on the bottom. Currently they are all off to the left and no matter what I try I cannot get them to centre up for me.

HTML:

```
<div class="Main">

    <div class="news-panels">
       <div class="news-panels-inner"></div>
          <div class="news-panel1">
             <div class="news-panel-inner">
                <a class="news-panel-link">
                   <img class="news-panel-image" width="235" height="235" src="./images/christmas_news.jpg" alt="Christmas News">
                   <div class="news-panel-header">
                      <hr>
                      <h3>Keep up to date with all Chistmas news!</h3>
                   </div>
                </a>
             </div>

          </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .Main {
       text-align: center;
       position: relative;
    }

    .news-panel1 {
            background: #747171;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            border-radius: 15px;    
        }
```

If anyone could tell me how to fix this it would make my day a million times better, it's driving me insane.

Comment: It's better for you to paste the source code here, rather than seeing a screenshot. It's easier to read. And, it's helpful when constructing an answer.

Comment: @aridlehoover I'll do that now, thank you!

Comment: Do you want to put them all side by side?

Comment: @DogukanCavus just edited the q there, looking to put them in a square!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels edited again

Comment: Now you included CSS for a element with the class of .Main but didnt provide the html for that part...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot center things by floating them. That takes the elements out of the document flow and forces them to either the right or left.

You could do this (quick and dirty):

```
.Main {
  margin: auto;
  width: 650px;
  height: 650px;
}

.news-panel {
  background-color: #747171;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Or, you could use the more modern [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll give that a try and see how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

You can center `divs` by removing its `float:left;`

```
.news-panel1 {
    background: #747171;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* float: left; */
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```